# Import PowerShell scripts or modules from a directory

Tags: powershell, import, module

I want to import a bunch of modules at once for various scripts based on directory.  For instance, if I have five modules in 'somedirectory\here\' I want a one liner to import them all.

How is this done in PowerShell?  Is there something like a manifest I can make with names of all the modules in it that will help me import them all?

Also, I'm already aware of user profiles ($profile).  That will not work as a solution in this case.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem "somedirectory\here" | Import-Module` ?

Comment: **See Also**: [Load all functions into PowerShell from a certain directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/763799/1366033)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, add this one liner to the beginning of a script, change the path to where you desire the files to be loaded and all is set.

To load the module (PSM1) files only

```
'G:\sync\Office\*.psm1' | gci | Import-Module
```

To load modules (PSM1) and scripts (PS1)

```
'G:\sync\Office\*' | gci -include '*.psm1','*.ps1' | Import-Module
```