# Where should newly written powershell cmdlets be stored

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I have written a new cmdlet. My problem is that I do not know where the cmdlet should be stored so I can retrieve and use it later.

Comment: It's up to you. You can save it as .ps1 file or as a [module file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules?view=powershell-6) so you can use it in your scripts using the `Import-Module` cmdlet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading custom functions in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764312/loading-custom-functions-in-powershell) (see also: [Load all functions into PowerShell from a certain directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763799/load-all-functions-into-powershell-from-a-certain-directory/763953#763953))

Comment: @Theo How does PowerShell know where to find the script to be run?